# incrond Error - access denied on /home/*/abc/ events will be discarded silently

Tags: linux, ubuntu, incrontab

I am getting following error on Ubuntu in the logs.

> incrond Error - access denied on /home/*/abc/ events will be discarded
>   silently

I am trying to monitor `/home/*/abc/` can be anything.

Any ideas how to fix?

Comment: Under which user you are creating incron entry?

Comment: root user. I am thinking this has to do with Selinux policies?

Answer (score 1):

**incron** does not support glob on path expression.

From the man page:

> where **path** is a directory or a file. Please note that incron is not
>   able to watch files in sub directories of the directory that you have
>   set, so only files in that directory will be observed.